# I can't add Digital goods (express checkout) in my Paypal account

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have a paypal business account and I possess non-Us/Canada business license. I run casual online dating site and pre-approved by paypal to sell monthly subscription digital goods.

The symptom is as follows:

In login profile -> overview -> my business type

If i add solution "digital goods(express checkout)", I cannot see it from dropdown or in any place. Instead, it shows just regular "express checkout".

I have tried adding all solutions in the "view all products", nevertheless I only managed to see 5 solutions instead of 6 in total.

I can conclude that i cannot add this solution.

anyone know how to solve above problem? I think 'Digital goods Express checkout is not enabled on my account'

It's going like this for almost 5 days.....

Comment: Do you get any API errors when calling SetExpressCheckout with PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital? If not, you can already use Digital Goods irrespective of what that page shows.

Comment: I do. Because obviously, digital goods isn't enabled on my account. and there's no way to add this (did all things correctly)

Comment: You can enable it via https://www.paypal.com/digitalgoods - login to your account from there and it'll add the right product to your account.

Comment: Same problem here.  Even clicking the [Get Started] button at /digitalgoods does nothing.  literally, it just redirects to itself.